# Slack APi Metadata (slack_web.json) Changes

Tags: json, metadata, slack-api, openapi

Facing issue while using slack metadata, earlier metadata contains example object in response, which is seems to be removed from newer metadata.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNxQf.png) --https://api.slack.com/specs/openapi/v2/slack_web.json

providing the link of older metadata json which contains example object for all APIS.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xS6y.png)
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slackapi/slack-api-specs/march-2018-updates/web-api/slack_web_openapi_v2.json

i used to generate output schema from this metadata which is failing now due to absence of this example object.please provide me any solution for the same

Comment: How do you "generate output schema from this metadata" (i.e. what's the tool/flow) and how exactly is failing?

Comment: i used to  parse  slack_web.json to Json object (slackMetadataJSON) than fetching example object to generate schema.. sharing the piece of code for the same                                       let examples = slackMetadataJSON.paths[completePath][httpMethod].responses["200"].examples["application/json"];
                           

                            let examplesSchema = JsonSchema.Types.resolveType(examples);

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there, preferably a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can reproduce the issue.